# Maximo: Create Reports feature for custom apps

Tags: maximo

I have create a new custom view in Maximo DB, added it through the Database Configuration.
Created an application on top to display the data based on that view.
Added new signature option CREATEREPT to use default dialog to create reports (Ad Hoc Reports).
When I try to preview any report in that dialog, I get the following error

> BMXAA8093E - The report could not be created and the cause of the
>   error cannot be determined. Try to create the report again, or contact
>   your system administrator.
>   null

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears error BMXAA8093E can occur in a few different scenarios where a problem occurs with a report and a more specific explanation can't be provided:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-trying-save-qbr-or-create-new-report

I would suggest first confirming if a more specific error or any additional information is provided in the application logs.  Following that you may want to verify that you have a Report Object Structure (ROS) for the object structure based on your custom view (i.e. in Integration -> Object Structures there is a record with "Consumed By" set to "Reporting" that has your object structure based on the custom view as a source object).  Although you mentioned adding a Signature Option it is not clear from your description whether a ROS (mentioned earlier) exists and whether Administration -> Report Administration -> Set Report Object Structure Security has been used to tie that ROS to an existing security group or groups.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is the solution that worked for me: go to Database Configuration, select your view, ensure that EXTENDSOBJECT is populated. In my case, it was not. You can fix this from backend. Let's assume your extended object is ASSET and your view is MYVIEW:
update maximo.maxobject set EXTENDSOBJECT='ASSET' where objectname = 'MYVIEW';
update maximo.maxobjectcfg set EXTENDSOBJECT='ASSET' where objectname = 'MYVIEW'; commit;
Do NOT forget to restart the app server.